# Crop Image texture on WorldSpace Canvas using RectTransform on Overlay Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, texture2d

I've been trying for several days to crop an Image texture (**Board** - originalImage in the code example) on WorldSpace Canvas using RectTransform(**CropArea** - cropArea in the code example) on Overlay Canvas.

[image]

The problem is that I can't find the correct coordinates of the cropArea on the original image.

I've tried with this:

```cs
        Texture2D croppedTexture = new Texture2D((int)cropArea.rectTransform.rect.width, (int)cropArea.rectTransform.rect.height);
        Texture2D originalTexture = (Texture2D) originalImage.mainTexture;
        
        croppedTexture.SetPixels(originalTexture.GetPixels((int)cropArea.rectTransform.anchoredPosition.x, (int)cropArea.rectTransform.anchoredPosition.y, (int)cropArea.rectTransform.rect.width, (int)cropArea.rectTransform.rect.height));
        croppedTexture.Apply();
        resultImage.texture = croppedTexture;
```

But the result image is not cropped properly. It is a bit to the left and a bit down.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify what is the correct coordinates you expect. In addition, what is the relationship between the code you show and overlay canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I have to consider so many variables. Here is a simplified version.

Need a new field: `worldCanvas`

```
var cropRectTrans = cropArea.rectTransform;
var origRectTrans = originalImage.rectTransform;
var origRectSize = origRectTrans.sizeDelta;
var pivot = origRectTrans.pivot;
Texture2D originalTexture = (Texture2D)originalImage.mainTexture;

// Scale pivot to pixel unit.

pivot.Scale(origRectSize);

// Get corners of the overlay rectangle in world space.
// The canvas is "Screen Space Overlay", so these positions are
// also the screen positions.

var cropCorners = new Vector3[4];
cropRectTrans.GetWorldCorners(cropCorners);

// Transform the left-bottom and right-top corners to the space
// of the original image. The translated position needs to be added
// with the scaled pivot, so that we can obtain the coordinates
// relative to the left-bottom corner of the image.

var cam = worldCanvas.worldCamera;
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
    origRectTrans, cropCorners[0], cam, out Vector2 lb);
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
    origRectTrans, cropCorners[2], cam, out Vector2 tr);

var point = lb + pivot;
var size = tr - lb;

// Scale the position and size if the image is scaled.

var scale = new Vector2(
    originalTexture.width / origRectSize.x,
    originalTexture.height / origRectSize.y
);
point.Scale(scale);
size.Scale(scale);

// Finally we get the correct position and size in the original image space.

Texture2D croppedTexture = new Texture2D((int)size.x, (int)size.y);
croppedTexture.SetPixels(originalTexture.GetPixels(
    (int)point.x, (int)point.y, (int)size.x, (int)size.y));
croppedTexture.Apply();
resultImage.texture = croppedTexture;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but unfortunately I get ***Texture has out of range width / height*** when trying to create the croppedTexture. 
I logged the size and it is pretty big: (194553.8, 191491.6).

Comment: Pivot before scale:(0.5, 0.5)

Pivot after scale:(606.3, 624.4)

Matrix:120.00000 0.00000 0.00000 72000.01000
0.00000 120.00000 0.00000 115200.00000
0.00000 0.00000 120.00000 -10800.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000

Size before scale:(115200.0, 175188.9)


Point before scale:(15006.4, 28230.0)

Scale:(1.7, 1.1)

Size after scale:(194553.8, 191491.6)

Point after scale:(25343.3, 30857.0)

Comment: The values are the same with the new approach as well. And still the same error :(

Comment: Update again, hope it will work this time.

Comment: It still doesn't work properly :( The position is good this time but the scaling is not correct - https://imgur.com/a/YQf6MMt. Thanks for trying it.  It looks like this is not so easy in Unity..

Comment: Here are screenshots of the world canvas (https://imgur.com/qWTZzN6) and the image inside it(https://imgur.com/tFOYs6x) in case it helps. I am also using the LeanTouch plugin to zoom in camera in order to select the area of the Board which I need to crop.

Comment: The size of the cropArea is not a square, and the scale values of the canvas and the image are consistent, so it's weired that the result image look square. Did you pass `size.x` (and `point.x`) as the second parameter? If not could you log the corners, size and point again?

Comment: Corner 0:(120.0, 230.0, 0.0)
Corner 2:(1080.0, 1690.0, 0.0)
lb:(-41.9, -24.7)
tr:(44.1, 106.0)
Point before scale:(622.6, 659.5)
size before scale:(86.0, 130.8)
Point after scale:(959.5, 657.8)
size after scale:(132.5, 130.4)

Comment: I copy pasted the entire code so I didn't modify anything.

Comment: Emmm I found the board image size is 2048x1365 but the RectTransform size is 1212x1248, does the sprite have a border?

Comment: Ok, I modified the rect transform of the Board image to fit the size of it (1328x887). Now it looks like the result image is exactly matching the crop area but the size is still like a square (https://imgur.com/ujUWdlu). The resultImage can be seen on the left side.

Comment: Looks correct, the result image is like a square is because you doesn't change the size of the RectTransform. `resultImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = size;`